# Не получается исправить You must call removeView() alertdialog в Activity

Tags: java, android

Что-то я запутался, диалоговое окно открывается когда происходит первый запуск,а при повторном вызове падает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Я понимаю,что это за ошибка,но я же передаю базовый контекст

```
public void createAlertInfo() {

    imquastion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PreviewActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name).setMessage(R.string.quastion)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_512).setCancelable(false).setView(mImagealert)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alertcancelbt,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

при повторном запуске диалог.окна падает на этой строке:

```
 builder.show();
```

Насследуюсь от  extends Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно ошибке вы пытаетесь добавить в диалог разметку, которая уже используется в другом диалоге. Он не помер после своего закрытия и всё ещё держит ссылку на разметку.

Вам надо не переиспользовать каждый раз одну и ту же разметку, а загружать её заново для каждого показа диалога.

```
public void createAlertInfo() {

    imquastion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View mImagealert = ...; //каждый раз заново загружаем разметку через LayoutInflater

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PreviewActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name).setMessage(R.string.quastion)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_512).setCancelable(false).setView(mImagealert)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alertcancelbt,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @upward, т.е. если как я в коде написал заменить поле класса на локальную переменную метода то всё равно вылет?.. Может у вас InstantRun включён? В любом случае разметку дл диалога составлять вне метода его показа смысла нет. особенно, если это поле класса

Comment: @upward, вы меня запутали. У вас работает или нет? И если да, то что вы сделали? Если нет - тот же вопрос.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб, все работает,спасибо.